# What is the error "unable to find api field in struct ObjectMeta for the json field "data"" in GitLab?

Tags: gitlab

During the deploy phase I face an error:

error: unable to find api field in struct ObjectMeta for the json field "data"

What is this?

What should I check?

Is it consequence of wrong project or wrong settings of GitLab?

Answer (score 1):

First of all, if you could post the object you're trying to deploy would help to find the issue :)

Most likely, this is a simple mistake on the indentation of your Yaml file. This often happens with objects that have the "data" spec, e.g., a ConfigMap, because of the proximity of the metadata field and the data spec:

```
apiVersion: v1
kind: ConfigMap
metadata:
  name: myconfigmap
  namespace: mynamespace
  # make sure this is correctly indented left!
  data:
    mydatakey: mydatavalue
```

vs the correct code:

```
apiVersion: v1
kind: ConfigMap
metadata:
  name: myconfigmap
  namespace: mynamespace
# correctly indented
data:
  mydatakey: mydatavalue
```

Hope this helps someone else.